# MS Word - How to create table of something

Tags: ms-word

Lets assume you create a new automatically numbered thing in word:

- Gnu 1
- Gnu 2
- Gnu 3

Now you want similar to table of content or table of figures a table of Gnus automatically generated.

How can you do this?
Is it only possible with Macro / VB?

Cheers,
Thomas

Comment: +1 for the technical terms. `Table of Something` & `Numbered Thing`. :)  Not sure how to generate the table, but I'd give it an educated guess of something to do with the font style you use to create the table.

Comment: If you have a better wording for this please feel free to edit the question. I don't think it has to do with font style, because how do you generate a table of items with font style?

Comment: In Word 2010 if you click 'Insert Table of Contents' the dialog box that pops up has an 'Options' button - this lists available styles with the TOC level attached to that style - that's how you'd generate a table from a font style.  How you'd use this info to generate a table of Gnus or any other type of antelope I wouldn't know though.  Sorry, I don't have better wording - I think yours explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for here
http://guides.lib.umich.edu/c.php?g=283073&p=1886010

So basically you need to select "Insert Table of Figures" and then you can customise it so that your custom style is used for the table.